# Convert an enum with a large number of entries from one interface to another in a performance critical code section

Tags: c++, enums

I have a couple of `enum classes` which I need to convert from one interface to another. If the `enum class foo1` has only a few entries, I find it way more readable to do the conversion using a switch-statement:

```
constexpr foo2 convert1(foo1 const& f1)
{
    switch (f1)
    {
    case f1::a:
        return foo2::a;
    case f2::b:
        return foo2::b;
//  ...
    }
}
```

The second, less readable and more error-prone (for example, it's hard to observe the addition or removal of entries in `foo1`) would be

```
constexpr foo2 convert2(foo1 const& f1)
{
    std::array constexpr map { foo2::a, foo2::b, /* ... */ };
    return map[static_cast<std::size_t>(f1)];
}
```

Now the conversion needs to be performed in a very performance critical code section. If `foo1` has a large number of entries, will there be any performance benefit from using `conversion2` instead of `conversion1` or is the compiler smart enough to basically compile the switch-statement in `conversion1` to something similar to what I've done manually in `convert2`?

Comment: In your first version, did you mean to write `case foo1::a:` and `case foo1::b:` instead?

Comment: Do `std::array constexpr map { [static_cast<size_t>(f1::a)] = foo2::a, ... };`. The only way to measure, is to profile or to inspect the generated assembly code. The performance benefit depends on so many factors within the compiler, that only inspecting what the result from your compiler is may help you. If the enum values are continues, `std::array` could be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want guaranteed constant-time dispatch, then you should implement it that way yourself. (your second bit of code)

Under the hood, a compiler will (usually) implement a switch statement as either a series of "if/else" tests, or a "calculated goto" (aka "look up an offset in a table and jump").

Which one gets chosen is something that many optimizers decide on a case-by-case basis.

[ Geezer mode ]
I remember someone writing a switch statement for baud rates thus:

```
switch (baud):
   case   110: /* stuff */
   case   300: /* stuff */
   case  1200: /* stuff */
   case  2400: /* stuff */
   case  9600: /* stuff */
   case 19200: /* stuff */
   default: /* more stuff */
```

and the compiler generated a 20,000 entry jump table, where all but six entries went to the "default" code. This was not helpful, as we were in a space-constrained environment.

Comment: `the compiler generated a 20,000 entry jump table` Do you remember what compiler that was? It sounds like a fun compiler!

Comment: It was a long time ago. :-) Lightspeed C? Green Hills? CFront? No, I don't remember.